# What is this gap above the fascia trim called and does it pose any ice-dam risk

Tags: roof

There's an insect-screened gap of about one inch visible above the fascia trim, if you peek behind the gutters. The roof has no overhanging eaves. Is there a specific name given to this gap?

[image: gap]

Comment: Could this be part of an ice dam *prevention* strategy? I have heard of systems where an air gap to the outside is provided under the roof diaphragm, I think to allow external and internal roof temperatures to remain the same to prevent the thawing over the (inadvertently) heated internal spaces which causes ice dams.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Looks like exactly what it is, so long as the vent path is kept clear above the insulation and below the roof deck (inside) surface.

Comment: It looks like there is such a gap in the diagram showing the fascia application of this ventilation product, though the the manufacturer is in the southern part of the country, where this is a more common approach perhaps? https://marcoindustries.com/ventilation/python

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a version of "continuous soffit vent" that is not in the soffit. Interesting placement. If ice damming does occur it will go into the inside of the soffit but it may not get to the wall and ceiling framing. If ice damming has occured before, there will be water stains as evidence.

Comment: There is only one room on the second floor where the ceiling shows a little staining where it meets the interior wall; it happened over 20 years ago during a particularly icy winter. It's barely visible.